# Add instance in AWX

Tags: ansible-awx

I implemented ansible awx through k3s (kubectl). But I have other servers that I would like to add as an instance to perform tasks in awx.
I've already researched and looked in several places where to make the inclusion and I didn't find it. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!